# tmux configuration to rename tab name to basename of working directory

Tags: tmux, keymap, button-remapping

I have this setting, which is supposed to rename the current window to my current directory by pressing `<prefix>.`

```
bind-key . run -b "tmux rename-window $(basename #{pane_current_path})"
```

For some reason it doesn't work. At the moment it gives me a 127 error. I tried replacing `basename` with `/usr/bin/basename` but that didn't help either. I don't know what I'm doing wrong at this point...

Answer (score 0):

Edit: My original answer was incorrect, and worked as a fluke. Kamil's comment below prompted me to reconsider.

The below commands work for me, including paths with spaces in them.

`` bind-key . run -b 'tmux rename-window "`basename \"#{pane_current_path}\"`"' ``

or

`bind-key . run -b 'NEWNAME="#{pane_current_path}"; tmux rename-window "${NEWNAME####*/}"'`

Comment: I had similar thoughts. Then I checked the OP's original code – and **it works for me** (Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS, tmux_1.8-5_amd64.deb). It is not perfect, there may be some problems if there is a space within directory name (proper use of `\"` fixes that); but I couldn't reproduce the OP's error. Your version also works for me. I wonder how it behaves in OP's environment.

Comment: Indeed OP's original command works for me (tmux 2.2 on OSX). I never tried it! That mine works is a bit a fluke. According the man, run-shell already does variable substituion.

Comment: This still gives me a 127 error. It's not like this is the only statement in the configuration file, but this one is the only that gives me such an error.

Comment: @hgiesel Which locale are you using? Perhaps it's a Unicode handling problem? Could you give an example of a path that generates the error?

Comment: @SatyaMishra I can even go to root and it will still throw that error

Comment: @hgiesel That's interesting! Could you tell us the platform and the locale? You can find the locale using `echo $LANG`

Comment: `en_US` and OS X (macOS) El Capitan 10.11. Nothing really interesting.

Comment: @hgiesel I give up. I have exactly the same setup, using tmux 2.2 (from homebrew) and it works fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

As you're performing an update you might to guard the operation with a confirmation step:

```bsh
bind . run 'tmux confirm-before -p "rename-window #{b:pane_current_path}? (y/n)" "rename-window #{b:pane_current_path}"'
```

Or

```bsh
bind . command-prompt -I "#W" "rename-window '%%'"
```

The added benefit of the latter is it allows further modification.